# Express.js - error when trying to pull data from mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I am using the following controller action:

```
exports.search = function(req, res) {

var x = [];

if (req.query.criteria == 'language') {
    var langQuery ="SELECT * FROM languages WHERE language LIKE '%" + req.query.val + "%' ORDER BY verbal DESC";

    client.query(langQuery, function(err, results) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }

        client.query('SELECT * FROM humans', function(err, hmns) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }

            for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                for(var j = 0; j < hmns.length; j++) {
                    if(hmns[j].request == results[i].request) {
                        x.push(hmns[j]);
                    }
                }
            }

            res.render('allHumans', { title: 'Search Results', humans: x});
        });
    });
}else{
    var query = "SELECT * FROM humans WHERE " + req.query.criteria + " LIKE '%" + req.query.val + "%'";

    client.query(query, function(err, results) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }

        res.render('allHumans', { title: 'Search Results', humans: results});
    });
}


}
```

My languages table has the following columns (id is excluded): REQUEST, LANGUAGE, VERBAL, WRITING, ASSESSOR

I have the following entries:

```
REQUEST | LANGUAGE | VERBAL | WRITING | ASSESSOR

req123       RU         3         3       name
req123       EN         4         4       name
req321       RU         5         5       name 
req321       EN         2         3       name
```

When I search for RU, my code executes perfectly, but when I search for EN it returns an empty array. Why is that?

Looking forward to your feedback!

Thank you!

**EDIT**: My humans table has a REQUEST column which is unique for every human entry. You could say that the REQUEST column in the languages table is a foreign key. (One human can have more language skills) The req.query.val  is RU when I search for RU (works perfectly) and EN when I try to search for EN.

**EDIT1**: Human entries:

```
REQUEST | FIRST NAME | LAST NAME | CONTACT
req123      John         Trump      000
req321      Mary         Jane       000
```

**EDIT2**: I've fixed it! I have modified the for loop. I think that was the problem :) I have updated code in this post as well. Still, I tried escaping the values before inserting the data into the table using ( client.escape() - function provided by the mysql node module), but it breaks it all! I get the following error:

```
ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server 
version for the right syntax to use near 'e'%' ORDER BY verbal DESC' 
at line 1
```

For some reason, after escaping the data, it adds single quotation marks to it and breaks the query.

Comment: In case of your `RU` which works perfectly can you give the value for `req.query.val`  and also for the second case where its not working i.e `EN`

Comment: What is in your humans table? You seem to be linking the results of that to languages table? `if(resultss[i].request == y[i].request)`

Comment: I've answered the requests in the post. See the EDIT :) Thank you!

Comment: Was the issue in the `for` loop what I said in my answer below?

Comment: Yes. After patching up the loop mechanism, it started behaving accordingly. Thanks a lot! Btw, do you have any idea why it gives me that error when using escaped value?

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that `y` (holding all the request rows if of the given language) is at least as long as "all the humans" (`resultss`), which seems to me to be almost always false.

In addition, you are not escaping the `req.query.criteria` and `req.query.val`, leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection attacks. You should fix that :)

(It would also help others if you posted the actual error message you are getting. And if you actually showed us a few `human` rows).

Comment: The problem is that I get no error! It simply returns an empty view, with no results, even if I know that there is at least one entry that should be returned